# How to call outer function's return from inner function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have such code:

```
function allValid() {
    $('input').each(function(index) {
        if(something) {
            return false; 
        }    
    });

    return true;
}
```

which always returns true as `return false;` affects anonymous inner function. Is there an easy way to call outer function's return?

**PS.** I am not looking for a workaround, just want to know the answer to original question. If the answer is "not possible" it is fine.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yeah, store it in a local variable.

```
function allValid() {
  var allGood = true;
  $('input').each(function (index) {
    if (something) {
      allGood = false;
    }
  });

  return allGood;
}
```

Comment: Which is not efficient as if first element is incorrect the rest 1000 will be checked anyway.

Comment: @serg555: then do `return (allGood = false)` inside `.each`. That will break out of the loop early.

Comment: @Roatin Marth - It's a closure run per element, it doesn't behave like simple loop, think of it as a function inside a function.

Comment: @Nick Craver: `return false` inside `.each` breaks the loop. It's a special case jQuery looks for. http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L537

Comment: Yeah if performance is going to be an issue (it usually is not), then `return false`.  The example did not make clear how many elements would be matched by `$('input')`.

Comment: What if the inner function is asynchronous (as in callback, when/then)?

Comment: Ignores asynchronous calls, which is a valid use-case.

Comment: @DerekHenderson sure - but the question is specifically asking about synchronous methods with useful return values. If you used asynchronous methods you'd be dealing with callbacks which is a different question.  FWIW this Q&A is from 2010, so predates a lot of work and proposals that have gone into JavaScript.  It will be possible someday to use a return value of an async function with `async`/`await` coming in a future version https://ponyfoo.com/articles/understanding-javascript-async-await

Answer (score 5):

You can also do this with filter:

```js
var anyInvalid = $('input').filter(function(index) {
  if (inValidCheck)
    return true;
}).length;
```

This works because 0 is treated as false, but it actually gives you the number of invalid, which you could use this to display "You have 3 invalid entries" or something if you wanted.

Answer (score 5):

You could also use [Array.prototype.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) which iterates until finding an element that matches the criteria.

```
function allValid() {
    var inputs = $('input');
    if(inputs.toArray().some(function(input){
        if(something)
            return true;
    })) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do this efficiently, I think this is the best way:

```
function allValid() {
  elements = $('input')
  for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) { invalidityCheck(elements[i]) && return false; }
  return true;
}
```

**Edit:** Although a more JavaScript-y version would probably use exceptions:

```
function allValid() {
  try
    $('input').each(function(index)) {
      if (something) { throw 'something happened!'; }
    });
  catch (e) {
    if (e == 'something happened!') {
      return false;
    } else {
      throw e;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: @Roatin Marth:  Thanks for the tip on returning from .each().  It's actually documented, I just missed that.  "http://api.jquery.com/each/"

Comment: I don't see how using exceptions is more JavaScript-y.  You should never be using exceptions for logic flows, in any programming language.