# How to check if deep object has value

Tags: javascript, recursion

I need to check if a deep object contains a specific value and return true/false. This object is not limited in the number of nested objects or arrays it can have.

```
// sample object
{
  "id": 2,
  "name": "Mann Anderson",
  "documents": [
    {
      "score": 36,
      "documentTitle": "Document Title: 8397640",
      "source": "RAND Data"
    }
  ],
  "emailAddresses": [
    "mann.anderson@kidgrease.ca"
  ]
}
```

And am using this recursive function to iterate through the object:

```
function deepQuery(value, q){
  if(_.isArray(value) || _.isPlainObject(value)) {
    _.each(value, function(v, k) {
      return deepQuery(v, q);
    });
  } else if(value.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(q) !== -1) {
    console.log(true);
    return true;
  }
}
```

The function seems to work (`the console.log(true)` appears when expected), but I am only getting `undefined` as the result of the function.

At first I thought this was because I was not returning the recursive call to `deepQuery()`, but as you can see, this is not the case.

Comment: Very strongly related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271919/return-from-inner-function-in-javascript and others(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509635/javascript-how-to-call-outer-functions-return-from-inner-function), might be duplicate.

Comment: It's probably a duplicate in the sense there are many answers on SO giving patterns for deep searches but I think an answer explaining the bug might be interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There:

```
_.each(value, function(v, k) {
  return deepQuery(v, q);
});
```

you're only returning from the callback you pass to `_.each`, not from the function. And of course returning would only return the value for the first deeper call, not for the first *positive* search.

Change it to

```
var v = false;
_.each(value, function(v, k) {
   v |= deepQuery(v, q);
});
return v;
```

or better: use good old `for` loops to completely avoid the problem (and to avoid continue iterating when the match is found):

```
function deepQuery(value, q){
   if (_.isArray(value)) {
    for (var i=0; i<value.length; i++) {
        if (deepQuery(value[i], q)) return true;
    }
   } else if(_.isPlainObject(value)) {
    for (var k in value) {
        if (deepQuery(value[k], q)) return true;
    }
  } else if(value.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(q) !== -1) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: This fixed it. Thank you. Can you explain the `|=` operation?

Comment: @Ryancrosser `a |= b` is `a = a | b` : it makes a true if b is true (it itsn't already).